# How can my app authenticate users with only a Stack Overflow account, using the Stack Exchange OAuth API 2.1?

Tags: support, authentication, api-v2.1, oauth2

Recently I registered an app in [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/) to provide a way to authenticate users with their Stack Overflow account.

Then I noticed that [Stack Exchange OAuth](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) only works for users with a Stack Exchange account.

I didn't find a way to set the authentication for only users with a Stack Overflow account in [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

I've faced with this problem because I want to collaborate with the [Django Social Auth project](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) for allowing the authentication with Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought there was no such thing as just Stackoverflow accounts anymore. every user has a stackexchange network account, but can choose which site specific "accounts" they have. The API works on the network account, so even if the user has only ever used stackoverflow they still have a network account and can use the API.